# Twig truncate with read more link

Tags: symfony, twig, truncate, twig-extension

I want to use the truncate filter of Twig. And it works fine.

I wanted to use as a third argument a link to read more about the article. But it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
{% set read_more_link %}
      <a href="{{ path('course_news_show', {news: entry.id}) }}">... read more</a>
{% endset %}

<p>{{ entry.description|truncate(150, true, "read_more_link") }}</p>
```

What comes out is this:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit met, <a href="/course/news/44">... read more </a>"
```

So, the link is displayed as text in the `<p>`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [raw filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) after your truncate filter:

```
<p>{{ entry.description|truncate(150, true, "read_more_link")|raw }}</p>
```

Comment: perfect, it works fine but without the " on the read_more_link. Ty very much.